# How to read JavaScript response from a URL in java

Tags: java, javascript

I need to write a simple java function that takes a URL and processes the response which is in  JavaScript, I tried using HttpUrlConnection, but it could not. Is there any java library for handling javascript response?

thanks.

EDIT: My code:

```
Url url = new url("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
while(reader.readLine()!=null){
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

Response:

```
<html dir="..... Windows Live ID requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked......<body onload="evt_LoginHostMobile_onload(event);">
```

But I want to read those javascript response. Is it possible in java?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by javascript response?

Comment: I can only assume that by "JavaScript" you probably mean JSON.

Comment: well, I added code. @BAF: server responded to the http get request using JavaScript that I guess, by default, java can not handle.

Comment: @Dylan : not actually, I can read JSON response using gson library.

Comment: Your code should not compile. `Url url = new url` should be `URL url = new URL`. Also your read loop will skip every other line. Also your `con` appears to be completely unused.

Comment: @Dylan: yap, that is typing mistake (I used URL indeed). con is not used at all! however, still I get the same reply....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way, H[tmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) does this, it can handle javascript response

Thanks all those negative raters .....